# Big Query Multiple Rolling Count

Tags: count, google-bigquery, rolling-computation

I have these data
[image]
I want to do two rolling count:

1. Count by every (id,refund) by rolling. When it turns into different (id,refund) combination (even with the same id), it will start from 0
2. Count by every id by rolling.

I want the output to be as follow:

[image]

Can you help me to create the query?
I try this one but it fails...

```
SELECT
    date,

    id, 

    refund,

    COUNT(CONCAT(id,refund)) OVER (PARTITION BY rn) AS count_id_refund,

    COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY rn) AS count_id

FROM table1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row_number() function. Here is my query with some sample data

```
with sample as (
    select 1 as id, TRUE  as refund,
    union all select 1, true 
    union all select 1, false 
    union all select 2,true 
    union all select 3,true 
    union all select 3, false 
    union all select 3, false
)

select id,refund,
row_number() over(partition by id order by id) as row_id,
row_number() over(partition by concat(id,refund) order by concat(id,refund)) as row_id_rf  
from sample order by id,refund desc;
```

and the result is:

[image: result]